# d3.js marker auto orient not working

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, markers

I started playing around with d3 to draw tree graphs and I am having an issue with the auto orient on path markers.  It seems that the path markers are not being rotated at all.

[image]

My markers are defined as:

```
defs.selectAll('marker')
                .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); })
                .enter()
                .append('svg:marker')
                .attr('id', function (d) { return 'marker_' + d.name; })
                .attr('markerHeight', 6)
                .attr('markerWidth', 6)
                .attr('orient', 'auto')
                .attr('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth')
                .attr('refX', 3)
                .attr('refY', 3)
                .append('svg:path')
                .attr('d', 'M0,0 V6 L6,3 Z')
                .attr('fill', getNodeColor);
```

Shouldn't these markers be being rotated to be aligned with the path that references them?

EDIT:

```
<svg style="width: 2000px; height: 600px;">
        <defs>
            <marker refX="3" refY="3" markerHeight="6" markerWidth="6" orient="auto" id="mymarker">
                <path d="M0,0 V6 L6,3 Z" style="fill: #FF0000;"></path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <path class="link"
              d="M1246.764705882353,15C1246.764705882353,63.142857142857146 277.05882352941165,63.142857142857146 277.05882352941165,111.28571428571429"
              style="marker-end:url(#mymarker);
                     stroke: rgb(31, 177, 230);
                     stroke-width: 1.5px;">
        </path>
    </svg>
```

Above is a super simplified example.  The result in the browser is:

[image]

Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mcottingham/LLud4kja/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the marker and you'll see the curve is vertical at its end and the marker therefore is oriented as expected.

```html
<svg style="width: 2000px; height: 600px;">
        <path
              d="M1246.764705882353,15C1246.764705882353,63.142857142857146 277.05882352941165,63.142857142857146 277.05882352941165,111.28571428571429"
              style="fill: none;
                     stroke: rgb(31, 177, 230);
                     stroke-width: 1.5px;">
        </path>
    </svg>
```